# Creating and using a multi-dimensional array from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the line I'm having issues with:

```
array('jsonrpc' => '2.0', 'id' => 1, 'method' => 'getExchangeAmount', 'params' => array(array('from' => 'BTC', 'to' => 'LTC', 'amount' => '1'),array('from' => 'BTC', 'to' => 'ETH', 'amount' => '1')))
```

This is the specific part of the line I'm having issues with:

```
array(array('from' => 'BTC', 'to' => 'LTC', 'amount' => '1'),array('from' => 'BTC', 'to' => 'ETH', 'amount' => '1'))
```

Basically I'm using this script to compare prices of cryptocurrencies.  The problem is that right now I'm having to enter all of them into the script manually.

However, I have a database table (`trade_stats`) that I'd prefer to get the details from.

Here's its layout:

```
id   incoming   outgoing
1    BTC        ETH
2    BCH        LTC
3    ETH        BCH
```

What I'm wanting to do is pull the rows from my database and use them in the script, but I can't seem to figure out how to create a multi-dimensional array.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be great.

Comment: I can't see how that dataset might become a multidimensional array. What might the array look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps you

```
<?php
$conn=new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Error Connecting To Database: ".mysqli_connect_error()."<br/>");
}
$sql="
SELECT * FROM trade_stats 
";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $from=$row['incoming'];
        $to=$row['outgoing'];
        //$amount=$row['???'];
$array=array();
array_push($array, array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to, 'amount' => '1'));
print_r($array);
    }
}

?>
```

I didn't set a value for mysqli connect so you can edit it yourself and suit it for your database.
+I don't know which column is for ((amount)) so I set 1 value for it.You can edit it yourself.

If you had any questions or if the code is not working as you wanted tell me I will edit it :)